# Junit testcase - error - status expected:<200> but was:<500>

Tags: java, maven, junit

Am running Junit test cases for my project module. After the execution of the test case am getting the below error report.

`ClaimControllerTest.shouldReturnClaimWithValidationResult:417 Status expected:<200> but was:<500>`

Am using the below maven comment to execute the test case for a specific module.

`mvn clean compile verify -Ptest`

But, my project have many module dependency. How can i execute my test case for my complete project ( will all modules )

The above error is pointing to the below piece of test case code

```
 mockMvc.perform(get(String.format("/claims/%d/validation-result", claim.getId())))
  .andExpect(status().isOk())
  .andExpect(jsonPath("$.catClaimNumber").value(claim.getCatClaimNumber().intValue()))
  .andExpect(jsonPath("$.validationResult.programErrorCode").value("UNTHRZD_EXTRNL_USR"))
  .andExpect(jsonPath("$.validationResult.hasErrors").value(true));
```

**Update 1 :**

Am seeing the below null pointer exception after doing Sys out

`2019-01-03 15:46:27,401 [main] ERROR   api.controller.BaseController:  83 - Unhandled exception while processing request for URL : http://localhost/claims/1901/validation-result with exception : null
java.lang.NullPointerException`

For the below code :

`mockMvc.perform(get(String.format("/claims/%d/validation-result", claim.getId()))).andDo(print());`

Comment: This seems to be related to Spring? As suggested in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28275059/4934937 you could simply print out the answer and get your exception (which is mostly the reason for a 500 error)

Answer (score 1):

It is telling you that instead of a success code 200 from calling your rest endpoint, it received an error code of 500. It means that your rest end point threw an exception.

you may want to print the full response with exception to further debug

`mockMvc.perform(get(String.format("/claims/%d/validation-result", claim.getId()))).andDo(print());`

Comment: Am getting the compile time error `a:418: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method print()`

Comment: @Karthikeyan add `import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;`

Comment: I added logs which i got from Junit exception. Updated in the questions

Comment: @Karthikeyan can you show the code at line 83 of BaseController ? it is throwing NullPointer

Comment: `LOGGER.error("Unhandled exception while processing request for URL : " + request.getRequestURL().toString() + " with exception : " + exception.getMessage(), exception);`   -- this is the code at the line 83

Comment: @Karthikeyan are you able to debug and check what is null in that line ?

Comment: `exception.getMessage()` this comes null

Comment: if i try to print like this `mockMvc.perform(get(String.format("/claims/%d/validation-result", claim.getId())))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.catClaimNumber").value(claim.getCatClaimNumber().intValue()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.validationResult.programErrorCode").value("UNTHRZD_EXTRNL_USR"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.validationResult.hasErrors").value(true).andDo(print()));`  its throwing method undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions:

1. Getting 500 instead of 200 - This is already answered by @mkjh
2. How to execute test case for complete project ( will all modules ) - For this you should try mockito (mocking other modules) because you cannot and should not take into account of all modules until and unless it's an integration test where in you make sure all the modules are up and running or else you will again end up getting 500 error which basically tells that there is some internal server error happened and in most of the cases it happens because of some services are not up